# XPath selector for Android layout

Tags: android, xpath, android-uiautomator, android-device-monitor

I am having a major issue to find a selector that selects four FrameLayouts [image: found here.]

I have tried xpath and UiSelector and I can't get either one to work. The closest I have gotten is the second FrameLayout using this xpath //android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']. I find it quite awkward that it returns the second element but not the first. Can anyone help?